# Remove null images in an Image Collection

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2, imagecollection

This is the code to generate an 36 length imagecollection from 2020 up to 2022:

```
var months = ee.List.sequence(1, 12);

// Create an image collection for each month
var monthlyImageCollection = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
  years.map(function(year) {
    return months.map(function(month) {
      var startDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(year, month, 1);
      var endDate = startDate.advance(1, 'month');

      var sentinel2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
        .filterBounds(geometry)
        .filterMetadata("CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE", 'less_than', 5)
        .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
        .median()
        .set('year', year)
        .set('month', month);

      return sentinel2;
    });
  }).flatten()
);


// Print the original and filtered collections
print("Original Collection", monthlyImageCollection);
```

but due to the clouds, there aren't any image in some month and there are some images with 0 bands in the results:
[image]

is there any way to enhance my imagecolloction?

link to my code:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/7c00ac10387a75dad7197f8205724dd4

best regards.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to remove null images in the Image Collection. You can skip the error message by using this function instead:

```
var addNDVIBand = function(image) {
  var opt = ee.List(image.bandNames()).size();
  
  var ndvi = ee.Image(image).normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).rename('NDVI');
  
  return ee.Algorithms.If(opt, 
                          image.addBands(ndvi),
                          ee.Image(1));
};
```

The function previously computes the size of the list of band names and if it is zero it returns a constant image and if not it calculates the corresponding NDVI and adds that band to the original collection. Complete code can be observed [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/8d35734e236add6d0a4baec608358d7b).

After running it in GEE code editor, I got following result:

[image]

At the Tab Console it is clearly observed that NDVI was satisfactorily added where there were useful bands. A image with only one band was obtained in cases with zero bands.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `If()` (ever), as it has sigificant performance implications.

You can simply filter on system:band_names to make sure all the images contain one of the expected bands:

```
collection.filter(ee.Filter.listContains("system:band_names", "B1"))
```